# Displaying image src in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I want to display an image within an iframe on my webpage. However, the problem is that I can't get it to expand to 100% of its size.

What I want to do is the following.

- Have a hidden iframe on my webpage.
- Call the first image of that iframe
- Display that first image on my webpage.

Currently, here's the code I have:

```
<iframe id= "Flickr" src="http://www.flickr.com"
    style="visibility:hidden;display:none"></iframe>
```

and

```
img = document.createElement("img");
img.id = "image_data_left";
img.src = document.getElementById("Flickr").imageSrc[0];
```

But with that code, I end up with the iframe and blank images.

Comment: can't access or control anything inside cross domain iframe due to `same origin policy`. ALso a good chance that flickr is using frame buster to prevent even showing their content in iframe

Comment: There's much better ways to access Flickr images ~ https://www.flickr.com/services/api/